# Restoring old Reminders Notes - MacOS

Tags: macos, time-machine, calendar, restore, reminders

I would like to access my old reminder notes from 2018, 2019. I have time machine and I know MacOS used to keep these files in a folder in the Disk rather than the cloud in old days. Your help would be much appreciated.